# O que faz o "delete" na frente do construtor?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, operadores, c++11

O que significa esse `delete` na frente do construtor?

```
Grap& operator=(const Grab &g) = delete;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note que isso é um operador de atribuição e não um construtor.

Ele está invalidando essa operação. Todo tipo em C++ tem o operador de atribuição criado automaticamente pelo compilador se nenhum for fornecido. Quando o seu tipo não pode permitir que atribuições sejam feitas com ele, esse é o jeito de impedir que o compilador crie o operador por você.

É possível fazer o mesmo com o operador de cópia.

Só está disponível a partir do C++11.